# Rails: javascript_include_tag :all purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, include

I have a problem with Rails and Jquery. Im using AJAX to add comments to articles without reloading them. The following code got automatically included in my views/application.html:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

Everything seemed to work fine, until i realised that the server console shows the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "assets/all.js")
```

So since this line doesn't seem to add anything to the application other than an error i deleted it. Next time I started the server and used the application all of a sudden every comment gets posted twice!? Otherwise everything still worked fine. So I added the deleted line again and I have no idea why but when I add the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

again everythings works fine again, only one comment gets posted as intended. However I dont want to keep this in the code since it throws an error. Can someone explain this behaviour and tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What's the Rails version? 2.3 or 3.0 or 3.1?  Notice that Rails manages assets with assets pipeline since 3.1. And the default application.js has jquery and jquery-rjs included by default.  But the routing error seems strange :(

Comment: I have rails (3.1.0). so should i delete everything but "application" ? However in my application.js everything is commented out..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3.1 uses sprockets to bundle javascript and css files. This makes the `:all` option deprecated. Sprockets use 'magical' comments to manage which javascripts are included.

So your `application.js` should look something like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

The first line also includes jQuery itself, so you don't need the other script tags. All you need to to is to point to application.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

If you're deploying to production, you'll need to run `rake assets:precompile`.

There is a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) on assets, which is a must see.